# Serve side request forgery by codeQl while make api call using restTemplate

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, veracode

```
@RequestMapping( value = "/data", method RequestMethod.GET)
public Response Entity<List<user>> getUserDetails(@Valid String userId) {

  UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(getUserUrl()).queryParam name: "userId", userId);
  //Some logic to validate url
  boolean isValid = UTILITY.isValidUrl(builder.toUriString());

  if (isValid) {
    result = restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);  
  }
```

In codeQl scan it is showing check failure

Server side request forgery due to a user provided value

How to fix this codeQl issue in spring boot